# AngularJS: how to wait a few seconds after typing in an input box

Tags: angularjs, debouncing

I'm trying to have a search input box fire the search operation a few seconds after the user stopped typing.

In a normal app I do like this:

```
  $('#search').on('input', _.debounce(function(e) {
    search();
  }, 800));
```

What would be the correct way to achieve something similar in AngularJS? Is there a specific directive?

Sample code would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can debounce using below directive...

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('ngDebounce', function($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 99,
        link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (attr.type === 'radio' || attr.type === 'checkbox') return;

            elm.unbind('input');

            var debounce;
            elm.bind('input', function() {
                $timeout.cancel(debounce);
                debounce = $timeout( function() {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                    });
                }, attr.ngDebounce || 1000);
            });
            elm.bind('blur', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(elm.val());
                });
            });
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i am using this [angular-debounce](https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce) module for the same

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="blah" debounce="500" immediate="true"></input>
```

this is how u use it

**EDIT**

to answer your comment...

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="blah" debounce="500" immediate="true" ng-change="search()"></input>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this triggers no search operation. It only delays the model update.

Comment: for that you will have to use ng-change... also please avoid doing operations using #id when working with angular

Comment: if that solved ur problem,can u please accept/upvote the answer